# Matlab: how to select a running task/application in Windows

Tags: matlab

I want to use Matlab to automatically control the mouse and the keyboard to operate a running Task/Application. I found Matlab code which helps to show process ID (PID) of running task/application. E.g.

```
[status,result] = system('tasklist /FI "imagename eq excel.exe" /fo table /nh')
```

However, how can I select the listed task/application (like left click on the task using its PID)? Since if the wanted task/application is not selected, I may end up to controll the wrong task.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this, and why with Matlab? I can't imagine that there isn't a dedicated tool more suited for this job.

Comment: Hi @Berhard, cause I have worked with the controlling of mouse and keyboard using Matlab before. Now I just want to make sure that I can select the task I want to controll but not the others. The tool for controlling the whole thing is not needed, just the one for selecting a running process.